# Using %systemdrive% in python

Tags: python, windows

I would like to open and work with a file with Python however I would like to use Windows `%systemdrive%` when referring to a file instead of full path. 
This piece of code works:

```
if not os.path.isfile('C:\\Work\\test\sample.txt'):
```

This does not:

```
if not os.path.isfile('%systemdrive%\\Work\\test\\sample.txt'):
```

Any idea? Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 3):

There is a dedicated function for solving this problem named [`os.path.expandvars`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.path.html#os.path.expandvars).

> Return the argument with environment variables expanded. Substrings of
>   the form `$name` or `${name}` are replaced by the value of environment
>   variable name. Malformed variable names and references to non-existing
>   variables are left unchanged.
>
> On Windows, `%name%` expansions are supported in addition to `$name` and
>   `${name}`.

```
if not os.path.isfile(os.path.expandvars('%systemdrive%\\Work\\test\\sample.txt')):
    pass  # do something
```

Comment: @Michel consider [accepting an answer](http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) if it was helpful.

Comment: I woudl do but as per the help: 1 Choose one answer that you believe is the best solution to your problem.
2 To mark an answer as accepted, click on the check mark beside the answer to toggle it from greyed out to filled in.
3 You may change which answer is accepted, or simply un-accept the answer, at any time.  I cannot find point 2....

Answer (score 1):

You can use [os.environ](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/os.html?highlight=environment#os.environ)

```
import os
import os.path
fn = r'{0}\Work\test\sample.txt'.format( os.environ['systemdrive'] )
if not os.path.isfile(fn):
    ...
```