# How to know where is windows installed with Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, windows, module

I am writing a program that needs to know which Drive is Windows drive . because I need to go to "Windows-Drive:\Users\publick\Desktop", I need some code or module that will give me the windows drive.
Thanks for your kindness.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I find where Python is installed on Windows?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/647515/how-can-i-find-where-python-is-installed-on-windows)

Comment: Run py -v in cmd.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If what you really want is the drive where Windows is installed, use

```
import os
windows_drive = os.environ['SystemDrive']
```

But it looks like what you actually need is the public desktop folder. You can get that easier and more reliably like this:

```
import os
desktop_folder = os.path.join(os.environ['PUBLIC'], 'Desktop')
```

For the current user's desktop folder instead, you can use this:

```
import os
desktop_folder = os.path.join(os.environ['USERPROFILE'], 'Desktop')
```

But I'm not sure that the desktop folder is always called 'Desktop' and that it's always a subdirectory of the profile folder.

There is a more reliable way using the pywin32 package (https://github.com/mhammond/pywin32), but it obviously only works if you install that package:

```
import win32comext.shell.shell as shell
public_desktop_folder = shell.SHGetKnownFolderPath(shell.FOLDERID_PublicDesktop)
user_desktop_folder = shell.SHGetKnownFolderPath(shell.FOLDERID_Desktop)
```

(Unfortunately pywin32 is not exactly well documented. It's mostly a matter of first figuring out how to do things using Microsoft's Win32 API, then figuring out where to find the function within pywin32.)

Comment: Thanks for your kindness.
Yes it is better.
Also I have to say that I checked your first code (Which is written by os module) and it has worked. So yeah It was so helpfull.

Answer (score 1):

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3


# Python program to explain os.system() method 
      
# importing os module 
import os 
  
# Command to execute
# Using Windows OS command
cmd = 'echo %WINDIR%'
  
# Using os.system() method
os.system(cmd)        # check if returns the directory [var = os.system(cmd) print(var) ] in Linux it doesnt

# Using os.popen() method
return_value = os.popen(cmd).read()
```

can you check this approach ? I am not on Win

Comment: try  %SystemDrive%  too

Comment: @ pippo1980 %SystemDrive% is works better but they returns "C:\\" and then 0.
I don't why; but it was done.
But anyway I thank you and appreciate you.
Thanks!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39193953/using-systemdrive-in-python Using %systemdrive% in python

Answer (score 0):

I found my Answer!

`import os

```
Windows-Drive=os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.join(os.path.join(os.environ['USERPROFILE']))))
```

This code is answer!